# AVPlayerViewController and AVPictureInPictureController

Tags: swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have PIP working using AVPlayer, AVPlayerViewController

By default, when entering back into the app/view from background with PIP active, I'd like it to return back into the view.

My issue is that when I setup the AVPictureInPictureController using my AVPlayerLayer, I can get back pip observations however, none of the pipController methods like stopPictureInPicture() or isPictureInPictureActive work or return false.

How can I get both AVPlayerViewController and AVPictureInPictureController to work together?

if AVPictureInPictureController.isPictureInPictureSupported() {
// Create a new controller, passing the reference to the AVPlayerLayer.

```
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            videoController.pipController = AVPictureInPictureController(playerLayer: videoController.playerLayer)
            videoController.pipController!.delegate = videoController

            videoController.pipPossibleObservation = videoController.pipController!.observe(\AVPictureInPictureController.isPictureInPicturePossible,
    options: [.initial, .new]) { _, change in
                // Update the PiP button's enabled state.
                print("Can pip")
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0) {
                    print("Stop Pip")
                   
                    print("\(videoController.pipController!.isPictureInPictureActive)") // Returns false
                }
            }
        }
      
    } else {
        // PiP isn't supported by the current device. Disable the PiP button.
       
        print("Can not pip")
    }
```